Error handling for Google's integrated product creation API
I would like to get detailed information about error handling for the integrated product creation API. Could you please provide me with a comprehensive list of error codes, including codes 400 (Bad Request), 401 (Unauthorized), and 404 (Not Found), along with their respective error messages and meanings? Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Best regards,
i need to catch it in my project backend (springboot)
